# Trying to get information from JSON file dynamically in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, json

I found this function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container')
        .TidyTable({
            columnTitles : ['Column A','Column B','Column C','Column D','Column E'],
            columnValues : [
                ['1','1A','1B','1C','1D','1E'],
                ['2','2A','2B','2C','2D','2E'],
                ['3','3A','3B','3C','3D','3E'],
                ['4','4A','4B','4C','4D','4E'],
                ['5','5A','5B','5C','5D','5E']
            ]
        });
});

</script>
```

And it gives me a table where I can click on the column titles and it sorts the respective column. Furthermore I have a json file with the following structure :

```
{ "results": [
   {
       "information1": "Some info1",
       "information2": "Some info2"
   },
   {
       "information1": "Some info1",
       "information2": "Some info2"
   }
]}
```

My question is:

Can I dynamically parse this JSON file into the above function? So I imagine I have something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container')
        .TidyTable({
            columnTitles : ['Information 1','Information 2'],
            columnValues : [ //Something dynamic has to happen here for all entries
                ['information1', 'information2']
            ]
        });
});

</script>
```

I am not well traversed in this area so being specific would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. One common solution is retrieve the json content with a request ajax. With the response, you can parse the json data and build the arrays (in the second case, it's a matrix, that can be represented as an array os arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's map method.

```
var data = { "results": [
  {
    "information1": "Some info1",
    "information2": "Some info2"
  },
  {
    "information1": "Some info1",
    "information2": "Some info2"
  }
]}

// assumes keys are the same for every object in the array
var headers = $.map(data.results[0], function(v, k) { return k })

var values = [];
$.map(data.results, function(row) {
  values.push(
    $.map(row, function(v, k) {
      return v;    
    })
  );
});

console.log( headers ) // ['information1', 'information2']
console.log( values ) // [['Some info1', 'Some info2'], ['Some info1', 'Some info2']]
```

Then it's just a matter of using your new data format in your function: `$('#container').TidyTable({ columnTitles : headers, columnValues : values});`

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ftoxw16/

Documentation on .map(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: The "assumes keys are the same for every object in the array" is giving me difficulties. I export the JSON file from a database I have on parse.com. If the keys don't have a value they are not in the JSON file, and the table I end up with have incorrect data in the columns. Furthermore I would like the data in a specific order other than the alphabetic order in the JSON file. So my new question is: Can I get specific information from the JSON file and put it in an array. Like, asking for only data where the key is "information1"? And if the key is nonexisiting, put in an empty string.

Comment: I think you answered my question perfectly and I will create a new question instead. Thanks mate.